# NavigationDrawer custom user touch action

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

NavigationDrawer can be either   LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED,LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED or LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN;

in UNLOCKED MODE user can close and open Drawer by touch the edge. 
when the drawer is Open, and user touch outside the drawer, the drawer closes. 
I want to avoid closing the drawer in this case, and I want to close the drawer only when the user swipe the drawer not touching outside the drawer.